# how to pass arguments to a function without invoking it directly

Tags: javascript, sqlite, asynchronous

I am working on a database manager for an app. At a certain point I want to save some data like this:

```
//call the saveBillEvent
DatabaseManager.saveBillEvent(model, callbackfunc);

//accepts billeventmodel object
DatabaseManager.prototype.saveBillEvent = function(billEventModel, callback){
     db.transaction(
        RekeningDelen.DatabaseManager.databaseInstance,
        RekeningDelen.DatabaseManager.saveBillEventSQL,
        function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            console.log('transaction failed billeventspersons table creation ');
        },
        function(transactionId, result) {
            console.log("transcation success billeventspersons, set firstappboot to false");
            store.setItem("firstAppBoot", "false");
        }
    );
}
```

The saveBillEvent contains a transaction which at a given moment calls the `saveBillEventSQL`.

```
DatabaseManager.prototype.saveBillEventSQL = function(billEventModel, callback) {
  //here i need the billEventModel to create the SQL
    db.executeSql(
        transactionId,
        getAllBillEventsSQL,
        null,
        function(transactiondId, results) {
           //here i want to call the callback
            console.log('billevent saved ' + results);

        },
        function(response) {
            alert('fail1');
            console.log("SELECT billEvent query failed " +  response);
        }
    );
}
```

This function contains the final callback, which should call the passed callback, for a certain query and also needs the `billEventModel` to create the query. Thus the billEventModel and the callback should be passed to this function, but that's not possible since the transaction triggers it at a specific moment.

So my question is how to deal with this A(with params)->B(has params, but cant pass through)->C(needs params) problem?

I hope you all can understand my question, if not add a comment.

Comment: i do not exactly get the issue. But, did you try storing the data in a global variable? ( so you need not pass the params).

Comment: The problem is that the saveBillEventSQL cant be controlled. I can not pass the callback through were I eventually need the callback(and the model). I could store the needed callback in a window variable, but thats not really a nice solution in my opinion.

Comment: If you cannot pass the callback function, the only other way is storing it somewhere and calling it elsewhere you need. If not global (i.e. window object), create a separate namespace and add the callback function and params as property in that.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I already guessed so actually. Could you expand on a 'seperate namespace'? Do you mean something like create a new 'class' and use that as some kind of transfer object with temp data?

Comment: See the first answer in this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/javascript-namespace-declaration